# Where to go now?

Tags: programming-languages

I'm a web and Linux developer with strong experience in C, PHP and JavaScript. I'd really want to take my skills further and expand into other languages, but I'm not sure what to choose.

I've considered Python, as it's very popular and is used to write a surprisingly high number of programs in Ubuntu and seems very useful to write programs quickly without worrying about lower-level handling yourself like memory in C.

I would like to expand the language base I have to be able to improve my career opportunities. At the moment, my work is currently with web development clients (PHP and HTML) but I want to write native applications too.

Comment: Very subjective question, I think it should at least be a wiki.

Comment: skill and career questions have found a great new home to exist: programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why not come back to old good C++? It is not THAT hard to write programs with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python and Ruby are wery nice languages, and you also my consider to learn lisp (scheme, clojure or Common Lisp) which is most powerfull programming language. You can compile scheme and clojure to native code.

Answer (score 2):

Try Ruby/Ruby on Rails. Python is good too.

Answer (score 1):

There are two may paths you may want to look, functional (Haskel, CAML) or Dynamic (Python, Ruby).  Was discussing this at user group, and there was a conversation about weather to learn for pleasure to improve you career aspects.

Answer (score 0):

How about C# and asp.net?